# Report on Scheduled Reminders

Tags: reports, scheduled-reminders

How do I get a report on the scheduled reminders the system sends on schedule please?

Under Reports there are Mailing Reports and I tried the Advance Search. However these seem to search for mailings done as news letter blasting and not reports on the automated scheduled reminders sent (for example informing the members that their membership will expire in 1 months time).

Thanks,
Sri

Comment: YOu may need to add this extension so you get an 'activity' for each reminder: https://github.com/fuzionnz/nz.co.fuzion.transactional

Comment: Thanks a lot pete. I will give it a try :)

Answer (score 3):

Schedule reminders add an activity type of **Reminder Sent** so you can use any activity report and filter on that.

Use the Activity Details Report or Extended Report - Activities.

Comment: Thanks Andy. I will try it. Your response is much appreciated.